# Using count() on a class that implements Iterator in PHP

Tags: php, count, iterator

Quick question really:

I've seen in bits of code in the past where the code could call count() on a object that implements Iterator, for custom Iterator classes.

I've written a class that implements Iterator and works fine in a foreach loop, but I was just wondering if there was an extra class I had to extend or function I had to implement in order for count() to work on my class, to return a value I want.

Comment: 'call count() on a object' do you mean `$object->count()` or `count($object)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have much experience with Iterators, but [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) looks like what you're looking for:

> **The Countable interface**
>
> Classes implementing Countable can be used with the count() function.

Comment: Yes that's right, I think I need to improve my Googling skills, I wasn't able to find this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have to do a count on your Iterator class, you can use the [iterator_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-count.php) function.